# Problem changing the state of the blue LED on an ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, c

I am trying to change the blue LED on my ESP8266. I can do this (sort of...)
In the setupWifi() function below, there is a loop that is supposed to rapidly blink the LED while wifi is connecting.  The only way I can flash the blue light is if the print statement (Serial.print(".");) is present.  If I remove this (and even increase the delay) the blue light will not flash.  If the print statement is present, it works as expected.

The other issue I have is when I click the web page to turn the light on or off.  The values print correctly, but the LED only blinks briefly on in both cases.

My questions are:

1. Why am I only able to change the led when there is a print statement in the loop while waiting for wifi connectivity?
2. Why am I unable to change the led in the main loop?

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <NTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define SECONDS_PER_MINUTE 60
#define SECONDS_PER_HOUR 60 * SECONDS_PER_MINUTE
#define SECONDS_PER_DAY 24 * SECONDS_PER_HOUR
#define SECONDS_PER_WEEK 7 * SECONDS_PER_DAY

#define LED_PIN 1
#define TIME_UPDATE SECONDS_PER_WEEK

const char* ssid = "ssid";
const char* password = "password";
const char* hostname = "hostname";

const long utcOffsetInSeconds = -4 * SECONDS_PER_HOUR;

SoftwareSerial ESPserial(2, 3); // RX | TX
WiFiUDP ntpUDP;
NTPClient timeClient(ntpUDP, "pool.ntp.org", utcOffsetInSeconds);
ESP8266WebServer server(80);

uint8_t ledStatus = LOW;
uint8_t lastLedStatus = ledStatus;
unsigned long lastUpdate = 0;

void updateTime() {
  time_t epochTime = timeClient.getEpochTime();

  if (epochTime > lastUpdate + TIME_UPDATE) {
    Serial.println("Syncing time with server");
    timeClient.update();
    time_t epochTime = timeClient.getEpochTime();
    struct tm *ptm = gmtime ((time_t *)&epochTime); 

    int hour = timeClient.getHours();
    int minute = timeClient.getMinutes();
    int second = timeClient.getSeconds();
    int day = ptm->tm_mday;
    int month = ptm->tm_mon+1;
    int year = ptm->tm_year+1900;

    Serial.printf("Time synched at: %d/%d/%d %d:%d:%d\n", day, month, year, hour, minute, second);
    lastUpdate = epochTime;
  }
}

void setupSerial() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  ESPserial.begin(115200);
  ESPserial.println("AT+IPR=9600");
  delay(1000);
  ESPserial.end();
  ESPserial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Serial Port Initialized");
  ESPserial.println("AT+GMR");
}

void setupWifi() {
  bool ledState = HIGH;
  Serial.println("Connecting to WIFI");

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.hostname(hostname);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, ledState);
    ledState = !ledState;
  }

  Serial.println("WIFI connected");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  timeClient.begin();
  setupSerial();
  setupWifi();
  delay(100);
  
  server.on("/", handleOnConnect);
  server.on("/led1on", handleLedOn);
  server.on("/led1off", handleLedOff);
  server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);  
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}

void loop() {
  updateTime();
  server.handleClient();

  if (lastLedStatus != ledStatus) {
    Serial.printf("Writing %u\n", ledStatus);
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, ledStatus);
    lastLedStatus = ledStatus;
  }
}

void handleOnConnect()  {
  server.send(200, "text/html", SendHTML(ledStatus)); 
}

void handleLedOn() {
  ledStatus = HIGH;
  Serial.printf("Turning LED: %u\n", ledStatus);
  // digitalWrite(LED_PIN, ledStatus);
  server.send(200, "text/html", SendHTML(ledStatus)); 
}

void handleLedOff() {
  ledStatus = LOW;
  Serial.printf("Turning LED: %u\n", ledStatus);
  // digitalWrite(LED_PIN, ledStatus);
  server.send(200, "text/html", SendHTML(ledStatus)); 
}

void handleNotFound(){
  server.send(404, "text/plain", "Not found");
}

String SendHTML(uint8_t ledStatus){
  String ptr = "<!DOCTYPE html> <html>\n";
  ptr +="<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no\">\n";
  ptr +="<title>LED Control</title>\n";
  ptr +="<style>html { font-family: Helvetica; display: inline-block; margin: 0px auto; text-align: center;}\n";
  ptr +="body{margin-top: 50px;} h1 {color: #444444;margin: 50px auto 30px;} h3 {color: #444444;margin-bottom: 50px;}\n";
  ptr +=".button {display: block;width: 80px;background-color: #1abc9c;border: none;color: white;padding: 13px 30px;text-decoration: none;font-size: 25px;margin: 0px auto 35px;cursor: pointer;border-radius: 4px;}\n";
  ptr +=".button-on {background-color: #1abc9c;}\n";
  ptr +=".button-on:active {background-color: #16a085;}\n";
  ptr +=".button-off {background-color: #34495e;}\n";
  ptr +=".button-off:active {background-color: #2c3e50;}\n";
  ptr +="p {font-size: 14px;color: #888;margin-bottom: 10px;}\n";
  ptr +="</style>\n";
  ptr +="</head>\n";
  ptr +="<body>\n";
  ptr +="<h1>ESP8266 Web Server</h1>\n";
  ptr +="<h3>Using Access Point(AP) Mode</h3>\n";
  
   if(ledStatus
  )
  {ptr +="<p>LED1 Status: ON</p><a class=\"button button-off\" href=\"/led1off\">OFF</a>\n";}
  else
  {ptr +="<p>LED1 Status: OFF</p><a class=\"button button-on\" href=\"/led1on\">ON</a>\n";}

  ptr +="</body>\n";
  ptr +="</html>\n";
  return ptr;
}
```

Comment: what do you want to know?

Comment: Why does the first case require a println and why doesn't the second case turn the led on and off at all (other than a brief flash when turning it on or off - which could even be the webserver)

Comment: your question belongs in your post, not is a comment ... this site is not a forum where you chat back and forth ... all of your question should be in one place

Comment: Do you know for sure that the LED is meant to be controllable? Pin 1 is the serial transmit pin, so I’d guess that the LED is really meant to indicate activity on the serial port.

Comment: I have read that changing it is possible and have been successful at doing so under the right conditions.  Your question is very valid and I didn't realize that they shared the same pin.  I'll give this a shot with an external LED, but I was hoping to use the built-in one for diagnostics :-/

Comment: calling Serial.print changes the pin_mode of pin1 to special. if you call pinMode before digitalWrite (or don't call print) it will work each time.